# How to "chain" inline list for bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is a beginner question, but I'd like to know if it is possible, using bootstrap's  list tag, to have them "chained together" rather than having them "stacked".

For instance, I have the script:

```
 <ul class="list-inline">
     <li>a</li>
     <li>b</li>
     <li>c</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="list-inline">
     <li>d</li>
     <li>e</li>
     <li>f</li>
 </ul>
```

Which returns...

a b c

d e f

How do have the output rearranged in this fashion?

a b c d e f

What I really like to accomplish is to have both displayed as separate divs inline

Answer (score 0):

You need to make to `float:left` both `ul`

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li>a</li>
     <li>b</li>
     <li>c</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-inline pull-left">
     <li>d</li>
     <li>e</li>
     <li>f</li>
 </ul>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inline-block {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="list-inline inline-block">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-inline inline-block">
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

UL acts as a block level elements by default, you just turn it to inline-block;